# Can I install a dual slot video card in a new dell?

Tags: installation, dell-inspiron

I am getting a gaming system for a family member, and was looking at a Dell inspiron 580.

I would like to know if the tower form factor case will accept a dual slot video card (such as the GeForce GTS 450) in the proper orientation, and is there enough overhead on the power supply to support a card such as that?

I had an issue with a dell machine at work where the motherboard is flipped in orientation, and the cards came off the opposite side of the board. This meant the 'handedness' was flipped, and the dual slot video card went up from the slot instead of down. The space where the second slot should be impacted the case.

Can I install a GeForce GTS 450 in a Dell Ispiron 580?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post includes photos of the back and inside of the Inspiron i580-5108NBC.  If this is the same model as the one you are looking at, it looks to me as if the motherboard is mounted on the normal side i.e. on the left as you look at the back of the case.

[Dell Inspiron i580-5108NBC Review](http://blog.itechtalk.com/2010/dell-inspiron-i580-5108nbc-review/)

[image: i580 inside of case][image: i580 back of case]

Regarding the power supply, you might need an upgraded PSU.  Most of these machines will come with a 300W PSU.  On the Nvidia website, [they recommend 400W system power for the GTS 450](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gts-450-us.html), and it has the extra 6 pin PCI-E connector which the Dell PSU might not have..  You can get quality PSUs at this kind of level fairly cheaply.  Something like the Antec part no 0761345-06201-5 or similar by Seasonic, Corsair or Coolermaster.